# GWT-RPC, использование типа данных "класс"

Tags: gwt, java, веб-программирование

Может ли клиент делать запросы серверу (сервер отвечать клиенту) данными, тип которых класс, определенный нами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Например

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserData implements Serializable {
    private String 
        id,
        login,
        descr,
        hash;
    public UserData() {
        id = login = descr = hash = "";
    }
    public UserData(String i, String l, String d, String h) {
        id = i;
        login = l;
        descr = d;
        hash = h;
    }
    ....
}
```

`implements Serializable` обязательно, соответственно все элементы класса д.б. сериализуемыми.

Еще один момент. Если в своем классе Вы используете класс из GWT (SmartGWT), например ListGridRecord, которого нет в jar-ах серверной части, то компилятор это не отлавливает, а при исполнении сервлета возникает ошибка (Exception).

Массивами своих классов (в т.ч. ArrayList<t>) тоже можно обмениваться.

Comment: Странно, если исходные файлы наших классов не помещать в один пакет исходных кодов с MyServise.java, то приложение не запускается и GWT Designer форму не открывает?